# Blocking access to a page in Page_Load method

Tags: c#, .net, javascript, client-side, server-side

I have a page that do some validations in Page_Load method

According this validation i need to block the access to this page.

Example:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    if (MyValidation)
    {
    // The page is loaded an de user get access
    }
    else
    {
    // Here, i need to block the access to this page
    // Redirect, close browser, etc ...
    }
} }
```

actually, a have this code...

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            // The page is loaded an de user get access
            Services.ChatService ws = new ChatService();
            KeyValuePair<int, string> kvp = ws.AtenderClienteChat();
            if (kvp.Key > 0)
            {
                this.CodigoChamadoChat = CriaChamado(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
                odsChamado.SelectParameters["cd_chamado"].DefaultValue = this.CodigoChamadoChat.ToString();
                fvChamadoChat.DataBind();

                // recupero da aplication a lista que contém os chat em andamento
                Application.Lock();
                List<chat_andamento> lstChatAndamento = (List<chat_andamento>)Application["ListChatAndamento"];

                // Instancio e inicializo uma nova chat_andamento
                chat_andamento ca = new chat_andamento(this.CodigoChamadoChat, kvp.Key, kvp.Value, WebUtil.GetUserId());
                lstChatAndamento.Add(ca);

                // Devolvo para a Application a lista preenchida
                Application["ListChatAndamento"] = lstChatAndamento;
                Application.UnLock();

                // Altero o titulo da pagina para facilitar localização do tecnico quando estiver com mais de um chat em andamento
                chamado c = (chamado)fvChamadoChat.DataItem;
                Page.Title = kvp.Value + " (" + c.cliente.nomecomercial_cliente + ")";


                // Envia uma mensagem de boas vindas
                Services.ChatService sw = new ChatService();
                sw.SendMessage(this.CodigoChamadoChat, "Olá " + kvp.Value + ", em que posso ajudar?", 2);

                //RetrieveMessages();  
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, typeof(Page), "RetMessTec", "timer_onTick();", true);
            }
            else
            {
    // Here, i need to block the access to this page
    // Redirect, close browser, etc ...
                // aqui é preciso abortar o carregamento da pagina
                // talvez mostrar um DIV sobre toda a pagina inpedindo interação do usuário
                  ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, typeof(Page), "CliAtendido", "self.close();", true);
                 //this.divGeral.Visible = false;
                 //this.divErro.Visible = true;    
            }
        }
    }
```

and this code give me this error

> ### Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.  Description:
>   An unhandled exception occurred during
>   the execution of the current web
>   request. Please review the stack trace
>   for more information about the error
>   and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   System.NullReferenceException: Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 173:    function
>   EncerrarChamado() { Line 174:
>   // Primeiramente mostra o combo para
>   seleção do motivo Line 175:        var
>   divMotivo = $('#<%=
>   fvChamadoChat.FindControl("divMotivo").ClientID
>   %>'); Line 176:        if
>   (divMotivo.hasClass('Hidden')) { Line
>   177:
>   divMotivo.removeClass('Hidden');
>
> Source File:
>   c:\Projetos\Avalon\Avalon\View\Forms\frmChatTecnico.aspx
>   Line: 175
>
> Line 175 have some JQuery statements
>   that retrieve a div inside a FormView

THE QUESTION 1 IS: Hoe to block access (Redirect, close browser, etc...) if the validation goes to "Else" part of my validation

THE QUESTION 2 IS: If my validation goes to "Else" the FormView is not created and if it is not created the javascript cant access it.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that i'am trying to access a control thats not rendered yet.

To solve the problem i do the following modifications in my code:

In JS a declare the variables that i need, simply like so:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var divMotivo;
    var ddlMotivo;
    var btnFinalizaChat;
});
```

Inside My FormView i put some script, to initialize these variables, so, the variables are initialized only if the FormView is rendered

```
                    <asp:FormView ID="fvChamadoChat" runat="server" DataSourceID="odsChamado" DataKeyNames="cd_chamado"
                    Width="100%">
                    <ItemTemplate> // A lot of things ... divs, tables, etc

                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            divMotivo = $('#<%= fvChamadoChat.FindControl("divMotivo").ClientID %>');
                            ddlMotivo = $('#<%= fvChamadoChat.FindControl("ddlMotivo").ClientID %>');
                            btnFinalizaChat = $('#<%= fvChamadoChat.FindControl("btnFinalizaChat").ClientID %>');
                        </script>

                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:FormView>
```

That's it

Answer (score 0):

Have you added a ScriptManager in your page?

Answer (score 0):

1. I would personally rediect using FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLogin() [or whatever it is called]
2. I think if you issue a return; command after the redirect the rest wont matter as the server will send the redirect which will redirect the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Response.Redirect("error.aspx");

Won't that work?

Comment: Probaly not.
If i dont enter here if (kvp.Key > 0) a lot of things dont happens. Eg: 
this.CodigoChamadoChat = CriaChamado(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
odsChamado.SelectParameters["cd_chamado"].DefaultValue = this.CodigoChamadoChat.ToString();
fvChamadoChat.DataBind()

then the FormView (fvChamado) is not created and the Javascript will try to access evaluate this.

Comment: Probably not ? have u given it a try?

Answer (score 0):

When the goes to "Else" simply show the user a message for the same and a hyperlink for redirection to another page.

Comment: Probaly not. If i dont enter here if (kvp.Key > 0) a lot of things dont happens. Eg: this.CodigoChamadoChat = CriaChamado(kvp.Key, kvp.Value); odsChamado.SelectParameters["cd_chamado"].DefaultValue = this.CodigoChamadoChat.ToString(); fvChamadoChat.DataBind() then the FormView (fvChamado) is not created and the Javascript will try to access evaluate this.